# Opening a VB Project form from command line

Tags: vb.net

So, out of curiosity.

I have written an application for handling our IT Departments 'Support Tickets' which has email notifications when tickets are assigned to engineers.

I might receive an email (from a random GMAIL account atm) that says Ticket ID - 123456 has been assigned to you blah blah blah.

is there a way, I could hyperlink from an email, to a VB form?

so based on the rules that the application is running, it could open a different form in the application with the information specific to that ticket? (that form already exists, and pulls through the data via a SQL Param (Ticket ID)

Apologies if my explanation is poor.

Thanks,

Dean

Comment: Why the sql tag? I see no SQL here...

Comment: @Jarlh I used the sql tag because I use a SQL query to load the data in a new form. removing it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. In fact, it's not even particularly hard, and I'm surprised we don't see more of it.

You can [register applications to handle different protocol schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx), so that in the same way Chrome or Internet Explorer might open up if you click a link that starts with `http:`, you can get your own application set up as the default action for custom protocols, like `ticket:`. Additional information in the url is passed to your application through the command line arguments.

Note that you must not only be able to update the application, but change the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT area of the Windows registry as well, which is not something standard-privilege users are able to do, and most normal installer suites don't have simple built-in support for this in the their standard version.